# Raspberry Pi w/ 2 ethernet ports

Tags: ethernet-port

I need to use two ethernet ports for a GW like target. Is there an alternative to the RPi, or a way mod the RPi so that it has two ethernet ports?

**Community Edit Note:**

The original content of this question has been edited. Originally, the question was debatably off-topic as a "shopping recommendation".  Since a bounty has been placed on the question, it has been reworded to more appropriately fit within the site's [topic guide](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: "GW like target"  what's that?

Answer (score 20):

You could always just use a USB->Ethernet adapter on the Pi.

Comment: Note that the existing Ethernet controller on the Model B is already just an onboard USB->Ethernet chip.

Comment: The maximum speed you can get with any protocol or service with an usb ethernet adapter is 5MB/s. I have one at home as a router.

Comment: [This blog post](http://www.midwesternmac.com/blogs/jeff-geerling/getting-gigabit-networking) is at odds with your statement machineaddict.

Answer (score 7):

Searching using Google I found [the Utilite Standard](http://utilite-computer.com/web/utilite-standard-specifications) device which has 2x GbE, 2 GB RAM, and a Freescale i.MX6 dual-core Cortex-A9 @1GHz CPU.  It's available on [Amazon for $159](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00FWWHNVU).

[image]
[image]

Comment: A great device: 2xRJ45-1Gbps, WiFi, Bluetooth, claimed fully working Ubuntu and even an SSD SATA included in the Pro version (Quad-core 1.2GHz). How sad the USB is not 3.0 (as for now, on June 2015): if you are planning to add more RJ45 devices, it makes the difference in speed.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some choices:

1. Use a USB-Ethernet adapter.
2. Use an SPI-Ethernet adapter (the same one people use on the Pi Zero). Raspberry Pi people prefer using the one with the `ENC28J60` chip on it.
3. Use both of the above, get three ethernet ports (two above + 1 built-in)

Comment: So basically you acknowledge that there's no alternative. Nothing in the same price range and spec of a RP.

Comment: @Benoît Partly. I'm not aware of anything that's on the Pi's price range that has 2 or more ethernet ports. Maybe some Linux-based routers.

Comment: @Benoît The question does ask, not only for pi alternatives, but also for ways to modify the pi to have a second port. This falls solidly in the latter category.

Answer (score 1):

we have developed the [EthernetBerry Dual](http://www.industrialberry.com/ethernetberry-v-1-1/) with two ENC28J60 IC.

Best regards
Pierpaolo

Comment: Would you have any speed data for this, perhaps in comparison to [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/54039/1501) ?